# Android Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have implemented MVP architecture in android app, and when i select item from navigation view, i switch the fragment using the following

```
citizenBundle.putSerializable(CCConstants.PRESENTER, 
ContactPresenter.getContactPresenter());
```

MainActivity,Presenter and Fragment all implement Serialiazable, but when i minimize the app the app force closes with the following error.

ccFragmentManager.replaceFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),CCEnumClass.FragmentsType.CONTACT,false,citizenBundle);

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.xx.cccare.presenter.ContactPresenter)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1761)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1709)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:777)
                                                 at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506)
                                                 at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1181)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:817)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1401)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:563)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1730)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1636)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:777)
                                                 at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506)
                                                 at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1181)
                                                 at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4860)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4176)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                              Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.xx.cccare.fragment.ContactFragment$1
                                                 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1233)
                                                 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1597)
                                                 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1558)
                                                 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
                                                 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
                                                 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1756)
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1709) 
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:777) 
                                                 at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506) 
                                                 at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1181) 
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:817) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148) 
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1401) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:563) 
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1730) 
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1636) 
                                                 at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:777) 
                                                 at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506) 
                                                 at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1181) 
                                                 at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4860) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4176) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) <!-- What are you trying to accomplish? (Please include sample data.) -->
```

Comment: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.xx.cccare.fragment.ContactFragment$1

Comment: ContactFragment implements Serializable. Do i need to change something?

Comment: can you show code for ContactPresenter?